# How to properly authorize through the API at Postman.com

Tags: api, postman, authorization

I have a server that at (site.com/api/v1/auth)
sends user data with the GET parameter.

I have a login and password for authorization, in return the server sends me a unique key. That is, after each successful authorization - the API key changes.

Here is the instruction, but I don't understand how to set it up correctly in Postman to check.

https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/pixel3655/democontent2.pi/1.0.0-oas3#/user/auth

Answer (score 0):

You need to send X-PI-EMAIL and X-PI-PASSWORD in the headers of the auth endpoint.

[image]

Then in the Tests section of the auth endpoint you can inject the id into your environment variables.

`pm.environment.set("currentId", pm.response.json().result.id);`

and use it on the other API requests by adding a header of X-PI-KEY and a value of `{{currentId}}`.